# sending Packet not work

Tags: packet

i want to monitor and send packet. i capture packets with wireshark and send packet with tcpreplay.my broblem is: when send packet with tcpreplay packet send sucssful, but nothing happen.
example 1 i open a address (www.mysite.com/test.php?id=1) whit browser.
after every visit that page in db of mysite a counter increase.
i want do example 1 with packets. i capture packet and send pcap file with tcpreplay but in db of my site nothing happen. why ??
example 2 i send a pm in yahoo messanger to my freinds  and capture packet and send captured packet with tcpreplay or with sendpacket software

Comment: why? Who knows. You've provided no code, just vague symptoms. We can't help you with the basically-nothing you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

this packet recorded with tcpdump. when send that with tcpreplay in my site conter nothin happen

```
ÔÃ²¡          ÿÿ     ¤_ïTP™ J   J   ÄnÝ-¶ 'Ý'ç E  <Ni@ @«ÃÀ¨M.P–“‚ P ËÆ¿     9@¾  ´
```

ˆÖ    ¤_ïTI
     B   B   ÄnÝ-¶ 'Ý'ç E  4Nj@ @«ÊÀ¨M.P–“‚ P ËÆÀ_Ö/€!@¶  
 ‰tmm¤_ïTÄ   v  v  ÄnÝ-¶ 'Ý'ç E hNk@ @ª•À¨M.P–“‚ P ËÆÀ_Ö/€!Q  
 ‰tmmGET /mani/test.php?t=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: dgmobile.ir
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive

¤_ïTŽ¡
 B   B   ÄnÝ-¶ 'Ý'ç E  4Nl@ @«ÈÀ¨M.P–“‚ P ËÇô_Ö0€§@¶  
 ‰Ztn”¤_ïTÅ­
 B   B   ÄnÝ-¶ 'Ý'ç E  4Nm@ @«ÇÀ¨M.P–“‚ P ËÇô_Ö0“€§@¶  
 ‰[tn—